# Python Minesweeper Game Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, game-development

I am making a copy of Minesweeper for a project in my class. My professor recommended that I randomly layout 10 bombs on the game's 9x9 grid. I was able to create the dictionary but am struggling with how to place the bombs. I have the squares labeled as a1, a2, a3..., b1, b2, b3..., etc. This is the code, which I have nested in the `main` function that creates the dictionary, and prints it out after the graphics window to make sure it is updating properly.

```
all_locations = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9',
    'b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b9',
    'c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9',
    'd1','d2','d3','d4','d5','d6','d7','d8','d9',
    'e1','e2','e3','e4','e5','e6','e7','e8','e9',
    'f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7','f8','f9',
    'g1','g2','g3','g4','g5','g6','g7','g8','g9',
    'h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','h7','h8','h9',
    'i1','i2','i3','i4','i5','i6','i7','i8','i9']

    i = 0
    gridDictionary = {}
    for x in '123456789':
        for y in '123456789':
            gridDictionary[x+y] = [0, 0, all_locations[i]]
            i = i + 1
    print(gridDictionary)
    print(gridDictionary)
```

I am attaching all of the code below, however, it is not completed and is currently just in fragments.

```
# Import Python libraries
import random, graphics
from graphics import *

def drawGrid():
    # Each square is 60px x 60px, there is 5px of padding along sides and top,
    # and 30px at the bottom to make room for info messages / user interaction. 

    # Creates window named "Minesweeper"
    win = graphics.GraphWin("Minesweeper", 545, 570)
    win.setBackground(color_rgb(250, 249, 246))

    # Outline of 9x9 grid
    gridOutline = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(5, 5), graphics.Point(545, 545)) 
    gridOutline.setFill(color_rgb(211, 211, 211))

    # Coordinates for squares: A1 - A9
    a1 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(5, 5), graphics.Point(65, 65))
    a2 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(65, 5), graphics.Point(125, 65))
    a3 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(125, 5), graphics.Point(185, 65))
    a4 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(185, 5), graphics.Point(245, 65))
    a5 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(245, 5), graphics.Point(305, 65)) 
    a6 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(305, 5), graphics.Point(365, 65))
    a7 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(365, 5), graphics.Point(425, 65))
    a8 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(425, 5), graphics.Point(485, 65))
    a9 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(485, 5), graphics.Point(545, 65))

    # Coordinates for squares: B1 - B9
    b1 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(5, 65), graphics.Point(65, 125))
    b2 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(65, 65), graphics.Point(125, 125))
    b3 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(125, 65), graphics.Point(185, 125))
    b4 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(185, 65), graphics.Point(245, 125))
    b5 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(245, 65), graphics.Point(305, 125))
    b6 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(305, 65), graphics.Point(365, 125))
    b7 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(365, 65), graphics.Point(425, 125))
    b8 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(425, 65), graphics.Point(485, 125))
    b9 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(485, 65), graphics.Point(545, 125))

    # Coordinates for squares: C1 - C9
    c1 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(5, 125), graphics.Point(65, 185))
    c2 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(65, 125), graphics.Point(125, 185))
    c3 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(125, 125), graphics.Point(185, 185))
    c4 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(185, 125), graphics.Point(245, 185))
    c5 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(245, 125), graphics.Point(305, 185))
    c6 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(305, 125), graphics.Point(365, 185))
    c7 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(365, 125), graphics.Point(425, 185))
    c8 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(425, 125), graphics.Point(485, 185))
    c9 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(485, 125), graphics.Point(545, 185))

    # Coordinates for squares: D1 - D9
    d1 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(5, 185), graphics.Point(65, 245))
    d2 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(65, 185), graphics.Point(125, 245))
    d3 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(125, 185), graphics.Point(185, 245))
    d4 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(185, 185), graphics.Point(245, 245))
    d5 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(245, 185), graphics.Point(305, 245))
    d6 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(305, 185), graphics.Point(365, 245))
    d7 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(365, 185), graphics.Point(425, 245))
    d8 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(425, 185), graphics.Point(485, 245))
    d9 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(485, 185), graphics.Point(545, 245))

    # Coordinates for squares: E1 - E9
    e1 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(5, 245), graphics.Point(65, 305))
    e2 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(65, 245), graphics.Point(125, 305))
    e3 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(125, 245), graphics.Point(185, 305))
    e4 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(185, 245), graphics.Point(245, 305))
    e5 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(245, 245), graphics.Point(305, 305))
    e6 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(305, 245), graphics.Point(365, 305))
    e7 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(365, 245), graphics.Point(425, 305))
    e8 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(425, 245), graphics.Point(485, 305))
    e9 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(485, 245), graphics.Point(545, 305))

    # Coordinates for squares: F1 - F9
    f1 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(5, 305), graphics.Point(65, 365))
    f2 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(65, 305), graphics.Point(125, 365))
    f3 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(125, 305), graphics.Point(185, 365))
    f4 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(185, 305), graphics.Point(245, 365))
    f5 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(245, 305), graphics.Point(305, 365))
    f6 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(305, 305), graphics.Point(365, 365))
    f7 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(365, 305), graphics.Point(425, 365))
    f8 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(425, 305), graphics.Point(485, 365))
    f9 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(485, 305), graphics.Point(545, 365))

    # Coordinates for squares: G1 - G9
    g1 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(5, 365), graphics.Point(65, 425))
    g2 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(65, 365), graphics.Point(125, 425))
    g3 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(125, 365), graphics.Point(185, 425))
    g4 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(185, 365), graphics.Point(245, 425))
    g5 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(245, 365), graphics.Point(305, 425))
    g6 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(305, 365), graphics.Point(365, 425))
    g7 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(365, 365), graphics.Point(425, 425))
    g8 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(425, 365), graphics.Point(485, 425))
    g9 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(485, 365), graphics.Point(545, 425))

    # Coordinates for squares: H1 - H9
    h1 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(5, 425), graphics.Point(65, 485))
    h2 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(65, 425), graphics.Point(125, 485))
    h3 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(125, 425), graphics.Point(185, 485))
    h4 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(185, 425), graphics.Point(245, 485))
    h5 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(245, 425), graphics.Point(305, 485))
    h6 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(305, 425), graphics.Point(365, 485))
    h7 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(365, 425), graphics.Point(425, 485))
    h8 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(425, 425), graphics.Point(485, 485))
    h9 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(485, 425), graphics.Point(545, 485))

    # Coordinates for squares: I1 - I9
    i1 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(5, 485), graphics.Point(65, 545))
    i2 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(65, 485), graphics.Point(125, 545))
    i3 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(125, 485), graphics.Point(185, 545))
    i4 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(185, 485), graphics.Point(245, 545))
    i5 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(245, 485), graphics.Point(305, 545))
    i6 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(305, 485), graphics.Point(365, 545))
    i7 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(365, 485), graphics.Point(425, 545))
    i8 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(425, 485), graphics.Point(485, 545))
    i9 = graphics.Rectangle(graphics.Point(485, 485), graphics.Point(545, 545))

    welcomeText = Text(Point(272.5, 560), "Welcome to Minesweeper, would you like to read the instructions? (Y/N)")
    welcomeText.draw(win)

    gridOutline.draw(win) 

    # Prints squares A1 - A9
    a1.draw(win)
    a2.draw(win)
    a3.draw(win)
    a4.draw(win)
    a5.draw(win)
    a6.draw(win)
    a7.draw(win)
    a8.draw(win)
    a9.draw(win)

    # Prints squares B1 - B9
    b1.draw(win)
    b2.draw(win)
    b3.draw(win)
    b4.draw(win)
    b5.draw(win)
    b6.draw(win)
    b7.draw(win)
    b8.draw(win)
    b9.draw(win)

    # Prints squares C1 - C9
    c1.draw(win)
    c2.draw(win)
    c3.draw(win)
    c4.draw(win)
    c5.draw(win)
    c6.draw(win)
    c7.draw(win)
    c8.draw(win)
    c9.draw(win)

    # Prints squares D1 - D9
    d1.draw(win)
    d2.draw(win)
    d3.draw(win)
    d4.draw(win)
    d5.draw(win)
    d6.draw(win)
    d7.draw(win)
    d8.draw(win)
    d9.draw(win)

    # Prints squares E1 - E9
    e1.draw(win)
    e2.draw(win)
    e3.draw(win)
    e4.draw(win)
    e5.draw(win)
    e6.draw(win)
    e7.draw(win)
    e8.draw(win)
    e9.draw(win)

    # Prints squares F1 - F9
    f1.draw(win)
    f2.draw(win)
    f3.draw(win)
    f4.draw(win)
    f5.draw(win)
    f6.draw(win)
    f7.draw(win)
    f8.draw(win)
    f9.draw(win)

    # Prints squares G1 - G9
    g1.draw(win)
    g2.draw(win)
    g3.draw(win)
    g4.draw(win)
    g5.draw(win)
    g6.draw(win)
    g7.draw(win)
    g8.draw(win)
    g9.draw(win)

    # Prints squares H1 - H9
    h1.draw(win)
    h2.draw(win)
    h3.draw(win)
    h4.draw(win)
    h5.draw(win)
    h6.draw(win)
    h7.draw(win)
    h8.draw(win)
    h9.draw(win)

    # Prints squares I1 - I9
    i1.draw(win)
    i2.draw(win)
    i3.draw(win)
    i4.draw(win)
    i5.draw(win)
    i6.draw(win)
    i7.draw(win)
    i8.draw(win)
    i9.draw(win)

    win.getMouse() # Pause to view result, click on window to close it
    win.close() # Close window when done 

def instructions():
    print("welcome to Minesweeper!")
    a = input("Do you wish to read the instructions? (Y/N): ")
    if a == "N" or a == "NO": #If user inputs "N" or "NO", skips instructions and starts game
        print("Let the game begin!") 
    elif a == "Y" or a == "YES": #Else-if user inputs "Y" or "YES", prints instructions, then starts game
        print('''In Minesweeper you are presented with a grid of squares, some containing mines, some not. If you click on a
        mine, you lose. When you click on a square that is not a mine, the square will declare the number of mines surrounding
        it. Once all of the mineless squares are turned over, you win!''')
        print("Let the game begin!")
    else: 
        print("Please pick between (Y/N)") #Exception if user does not input correctly
        main() #Restarts the program

def numbersofneighbors(gridDictionary):
    for l,k in gridDictionary.items():
        r,c=int(l[0]),int(l[1])
        neighbortiles=[(r-1,c),(r-1,c-1),(r,c-1),(r+1,c-1),(r+1,c),(r+1,c+1),(r,c+1),(r-1,c+1)]
        for n in neighbortiles:
            if 1 <= n[0] <= 9 and 1 <= n[1] <= 9 and k[0]!=0:
                key=str(n[0])+str(n[1])
                gridDictionary[key][1]+=1
    return gridDictionary

def main():
    drawGrid()

    #Assigns (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) values for A1 - A9
    a1 = [(5, 5), (65, 65)]
    a2 = [(65, 5), (125, 65)]
    a3 = [(125, 5), (185, 65)]
    a4 = [(185, 5), (245, 65)]
    a5 = [(245, 5), (305, 65)] 
    a6 = [(305, 5), (365, 65)]
    a7 = [(365, 5), (425, 65)]
    a8 = [(425, 5), (485, 65)]
    a9 = [(485, 5), (545, 65)]

    #Assigns (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) values for B1 - B9
    b1 = [(5, 65), (65, 125)]
    b2 = [(65, 65), (125, 125)]
    b3 = [(125, 65), (185, 125)]
    b4 = [(185, 65), (245, 125)]
    b5 = [(245, 65), (305, 125)]
    b6 = [(305, 65), (365, 125)]
    b7 = [(365, 65), (425, 125)]
    b8 = [(425, 65), (485, 125)]
    b9 = [(485, 65), (545, 125)]

    #Assigns (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) values for C1 - C9
    c1 = [(5, 125), (65, 185)]
    c2 = [(65, 125), (125, 185)]
    c3 = [(125, 125), (185, 185)]
    c4 = [(185, 125), (245, 185)]
    c5 = [(245, 125), (305, 185)]
    c6 = [(305, 125), (365, 185)]
    c7 = [(365, 125), (425, 185)]
    c8 = [(425, 125), (485, 185)]
    c9 = [(485, 125), (545, 185)]

    #Assigns (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) values for D1 - D9
    d1 = [(5, 185), (65, 245)]
    d2 = [(65, 185), (125, 245)]
    d3 = [(125, 185), (185, 245)]
    d4 = [(185, 185), (245, 245)]
    d5 = [(245, 185), (305, 245)]
    d6 = [(305, 185), (365, 245)]
    d7 = [(365, 185), (425, 245)]
    d8 = [(425, 185), (485, 245)]
    d9 = [(485, 185), (545, 245)]

    #Assigns (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) values for E1 - E9
    e1 = [(5, 245), (65, 305)]
    e2 = [(65, 245), (125, 305)]
    e3 = [(125, 245), (185, 305)]
    e4 = [(185, 245), (245, 305)]
    e5 = [(245, 245), (305, 305)]
    e6 = [(305, 245), (365, 305)]
    e7 = [(365, 245), (425, 305)]
    e8 = [(425, 245), (485, 305)]
    e9 = [(485, 245), (545, 305)]

    #Assigns (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) values for F1 - F9
    f1 = [(5, 305), (65, 365)]
    f2 = [(65, 305), (125, 365)]
    f3 = [(125, 305), (185, 365)]
    f4 = [(185, 305), (245, 365)]
    f5 = [(245, 305), (305, 365)]
    f6 = [(305, 305), (365, 365)]
    f7 = [(365, 305), (425, 365)]
    f8 = [(425, 305), (485, 365)]
    f9 = [(485, 305), (545, 365)]

    #Assigns (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) values for G1 - G9
    g1 = [(5, 365), (65, 425)]
    g2 = [(65, 365), (125, 425)]
    g3 = [(125, 365), (185, 425)]
    g4 = [(185, 365), (245, 425)]
    g5 = [(245, 365), (305, 425)]
    g6 = [(305, 365), (365, 425)]
    g7 = [(365, 365), (425, 425)]
    g8 = [(425, 365), (485, 425)]
    g9 = [(485, 365), (545, 425)]

    #Assigns (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) values for H1 - H9
    h1 = [(5, 425), (65, 485)]
    h2 = [(65, 425), (125, 485)]
    h3 = [(125, 425), (185, 485)]
    h4 = [(185, 425), (245, 485)]
    h5 = [(245, 425), (305, 485)]
    h6 = [(305, 425), (365, 485)]
    h7 = [(365, 425), (425, 485)]
    h8 = [(425, 425), (485, 485)]
    h9 = [(485, 425), (545, 485)]

    #Assigns (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) values for I1 - I9
    i1 = [(5, 485), (65, 545)]
    i2 = [(65, 485), (125, 545)]
    i3 = [(125, 485), (185, 545)]
    i4 = [(185, 485), (245, 545)]
    i5 = [(245, 485), (305, 545)]
    i6 = [(305, 485), (365, 545)]
    i7 = [(365, 485), (425, 545)]
    i8 = [(425, 485), (485, 545)]
    i9 = [(485, 485), (545, 545)]
    
    all_locations = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9',
    'b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b9',
    'c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9',
    'd1','d2','d3','d4','d5','d6','d7','d8','d9',
    'e1','e2','e3','e4','e5','e6','e7','e8','e9',
    'f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7','f8','f9',
    'g1','g2','g3','g4','g5','g6','g7','g8','g9',
    'h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','h7','h8','h9',
    'i1','i2','i3','i4','i5','i6','i7','i8','i9']

    i = 0
    gridDictionary = {}
    for x in '123456789':
        for y in '123456789':
            gridDictionary[x+y] = [0, 0, all_locations[i]]
            i = i + 1
    print(gridDictionary)
    
main() #Runs the program
```

I am currently lost as to how I should continue to develop my code, and any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're copy/pasting code, it's a clue you should be doing something different,  like converting it to a loop, or a function (or both).  You have done a LOT of copy/pasting code!  For example ` x1.draw(win) [...]`  could just be `for location in all_locations:` `location.draw`  the same applies to everywhere you have one line per grid square..

Comment: Please use lists instead of `i1`, `i2`, `i3`... This design is going to be impossible to work with if it isn't already. Take the time to refactor everything into simple data structures, e.g. `board`, where `board` is the entire 2d grid of cells.

Comment: Consider doing this entire program without graphics.  Focus on the logic for the minesweeper game itself.   Separately, you can write a function to draw the game board in its current state.  I think you will learn a lot more this way - since the game logic is fun.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach for building a minesweeper board (or grid):

```
import random
import columnar

class Square:

  squares = []

  def __init__( self, x,y ):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.bomb = False
    self.neighbor = 0
    Square.squares.append( self )


  def __repr__(self):
    if self.bomb:
      return " X "
    if self.neighbor > 0:
      return f" {self.neighbor} "
    return " "


#random.seed(10) # include this line to trouble shoot
rows = 9
cols = 9
bombs = 10
grid = [ [ Square(c,r) for c in range(cols)] for r in range(rows)]
random.shuffle( Square.squares )

for sq in Square.squares[:bombs]:
  sq.bomb = True
  for y in range(-1,2):
    for x in range(-1,2):
        if y + sq.y >= 0 and y + sq.y < rows and x + sq.x >= 0  and x + sq.x < cols:
          grid[ sq.y + y ][ sq.x + x  ].neighbor += 1

# Here's a visualization - you can remove columnar calls (and table) if you don't want to install columnar package
table = columnar.columnar(grid)
print(table)
print(grid)
```